# adjust font size to width on dynamically resizing button, button doesn't have a width static constraint

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have three buttons that end up pretty close together when in iPad adaptability mode, but then far apart when in iPad or iPhone landscape. I have the buttons scale correctly using static trailing/leading/bottom space constraints and their height is set proportional to the view height. The buttons resize nicely but I have to set all the button label font sizes programmatically for different screen sizes in viewdidload. I was hoping I could add resizable title labels functionality in my class but I cant seem to lock it in.

Any help would be appreciated.

My custom button class:

```
    import UIKit

class BetterButton: UIButton {

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Comp", size: 200)
    self.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 0
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor

}

}
```

All the buttons text is at 200 at runtime, but the adjust to width doesn't activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
self.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByClipping
```

Also, font size of 200 with a minimumScaleFactor of 0.5 results in a smallest font size of 100, which is still pretty darn big.

Changing minimumScaleFactor to 0.1 or 0.05, or changing max / normal font size to something like 30 will do the trick.

Comment: this kept the text orientation on the buttons going from left to right inside the button, but the font is still huge and just goes way passed the button bounds because the font is huge. (prior to adding this line the text would be large and explode out from all sides of the button)  but this did not allow the title text to resize or shrink to fit.

Comment: Hmmm... What happens if you try `minimumScaleFactor = 0.05`? Because 0.5*200 is still a pretty darn big font...

Comment: Oh! I thought it was minimum scale as in the minimum font size it would shrink to, I didn't notice it was a factor of the font size. I changed font size to 30 and the scale factor at .5 seems to do the trick. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cool - I added notes on that to my answer. If you "accept" it, that can help others who may come across this question. Glad you got it worked out :)